# morphTo function returns null, although relationship exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I created a polymorphic relationship, which works. Just when trying to retrieve the "parent" (with `with`) the result is `null`.

Assume there are some tables / models that need a special relation for caching.

**Migration**

```
class CreateSearchCachesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('search_caches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('searchable');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->morphs('searchCacheable');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class SearchCache extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'searchable',
        'url'
    ];

    public function searchCacheable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Saving using `$model->searchCache()->save($searchCache);` works.

[image]

But when trying to retrieve the relationship it shows up as null:

```
$results = SearchCache::query();

        foreach ($search as $searchString) {
            $results = $results->where('searchable', 'like', "%$searchString%");
        }

        $results = $results->with('searchCacheable')->get();

        dd($results);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to lie with using CamelCase in the name. So please be warned to check that first.

Renaming from `searchCacheable` to `searchcacheable` fixed it.